# FontFamily для UWP с поддержкой Emoji и кириллицы

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Необходимо в TextBlock выводить некий символ (одна буква или emoji). Никак не могу подобрать шрифт, либо буквы либо emoji отображаются квадратиком.

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding displayTransTags, Converter={StaticResource tagLetter}}"/>
```

Конвертер берет текст из переменной displayTransTags и возвращает первый символ.

Какой FontFamily использовать что бы все символы отображались корректно?

UPD: Похоже квадратики появляются из за использования конвертера.

```
return ((string)value).Substring(0, 1);
```

Как можно реализовать по другому?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно не самый рациональный вариант, но для меня сработало двойное преобразование символа:

```
return char.ConvertFromUtf32(char.ConvertToUtf32(((string)value), 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Это смотря в каком шрифте у вас иконки. Самый простой вариант вот:

```
<TextBlock 
    Text="{Binding displayTransTags}"
    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
```

Если вам надо в одном `TextBlock` выводить и текст, и иконки, тогда можно сделать так:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run
        Text="{Binding text}" />
    <Run
        Text="{Binding icon}"
        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"></Run>
</TextBlock>
```